# A word that means "un-waning''

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I wanted to use the word "unwaning" (or, perhaps, un-waning), as in "for his unwaning enthusiasm". However, no decent (online) dictionary I've consulted seems to recognize it. What other word would you use? Does "unwaning" sound weird, or does it sound right to a native speaker?

Comment: Voting to close, on the grounds that when I Googled *define wane* and followed the first link, the definition ended with *(compare 'wax')*. **And** the fourth link shown by Google was headed **Wax and wane | Define Wax and wane at Dictionary.com**

Comment: Take into account that the OP may not need the word _waxing_.  _Waxing_ would not fit in his context.  _Unwaning_ would mean _not getting weaker_, whereas _waxing_ means _getting stronger_.  There's a difference.  Two kinds of opposite, as it were.

Comment: @drm65: The OP asked for an antonym. Words either mean something or they don't.

Comment: Is there a word for the relationship between _waning_ and _unflagging_?  If there is, that's the word the OP needs in his question.

Comment: You could just use "unwaning". People will know what it means. And it's in some pretty good dictionaries. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwaning

Comment: @VincentMcNabb, agree. *Unrelenting* is also close, if Jan wants a more commonly used word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the word *enthusiasm*, you may want the word [*unflagging*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unflagging), or some synonym:

> ...for his *unflagging* enthusiasm.

Comment: As far as un- words go, "unflagging" seems to be popular with enthusiasm.

Comment: okay, this is probably the word i've been looking for.. thank you!

Comment: Actually, the word I more often here is is `unwavering`.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly: [unwaning is a word](http://thesaurus.com/browse/unwaning). I understood what you meant when I read it.

But if you are looking for a substitute then I would use [unwavering](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unwavering)

> **unwavering** *adj* - not wavering or hesitant; resolute

Comment: hmm, thanks for the not on unwaning! Could have used it after all :)!

Answer (score 4):

The antonym of *waning* is *waxing*. Look at the cycles of the moon.

Comment: Waxing means "growing" though. The OP asks for something that means not diminishing.

Comment: @Kit: Then maybe the OP should rephrase the title of the question and remove *antonym*.

Comment: I agree this is the best answer to the question in the title :) Too bad it's not what the questioner meant to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it's the meaning you are looking for, but "[unbridled enthusiasm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unbridled)" is a common English expression for unlimited amounts of excitement.

If you want something more like constant and steady excitement, "unwavering enthusiasm" might also suit.