# What is a word for the relationship between "waning" and "non-waning"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35568/10041), an antonym for *waning* was requested.  *Waxing* was naturally suggested, but the OP declined the word because he was actually looking for a word meaning *non-waning*, and thought that "antonym" was the word to describe his request.

The difference is: *waxing* means *getting stronger/more intense* and *non-waning*, if it were a word, would mean *unchanging* (not getting either stronger or weaker).

What is the difference between the words actually called, if not antonymous?

Comment: A better way to express the intended relationship is "waning" and "non-waning".  "Un-" often has the sense of "reversal" (dictionary.com says 'un-' is "a prefix freely used in English to form verbs expressing a reversal of some action or state" (2nd definition)), while "Non-" is almost exclusively for negation.

Comment: @Hellion: You are right, and I edited

Comment: @Hellion: Oh, heh. Yeah, I mistook _un-_ as reversal, obviously, for my answer.

Comment: @MrHen: Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options here would be *reciprocal*:

> *Mathematics* (of a quantity or function) related to another so that their product is one

This isn't quite as translatable into normal usage because the standard use of *reciprocal* means something more akin to *equal* or *mutual*.

Another option is *reversal*:

> a change to an opposite direction, position, or course of action

While the opposite of *wane* is *wax*, the *reversal* of *wane* would be an *un-wane*. The subtle difference here is key:

> The opposite of scoring a goal is not scoring a goal.
>
> The reversal of scoring a goal is to take back the goal.

Hitting up a thesaurus then provides these alternatives:

- undoing
- countering
- overriding
- revocation
- repeal

And so on. Many words do not have appropriate *reversals* or *antonyms* and sometimes the same word can work for both.

---

In response to the edit, *non-* adds a third option to the pool which means "Not in the state of." This could be seen as an *absence* or *negation*. Much like how *reversal* and *opposite* can both apply, *absence* can fit into the same word as well:

> This is hot; that is cold.

*Hot* is the opposite of *cold*; *cold* is also the absence of *heat*.

Comment: But there's no grammatical term?

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself when you first say *reversal is "a change to an opposite direction"*, then that *the reversal of wane [is] un-wane*. If the opposite/reverse distinction applies, then per OP and your "score a goal" it follows that *wax* is the reversal, and *un-wane* is the opposite (i.e. - not waning, not changing phase at all).

Comment: @drm: I don't understand. What do you mean by grammatical term? You didn't mention anything like that in your question. If I understand correctly, both _opposites_ and _reversals_ would qualify as _antonyms_.

Comment: I mean no word on the level of _synonym_, _antonym_, etc.

Comment: @drm65: There won't be a "grammatical term" clarifying which "kind" of "opposite" is involved in any particular case, because there are so many different kinds in the first place. Which is one reason why I don't think EL&U should have too many questions about synonyms and antonyms. They are interpretive mental constructs, not real-world facts reflected by language.

Comment: @Fumble: I am not actually contradicting myself at all and explicitly point out that sometimes the same word is used for _both_ an opposite and a reversal. Wane/wax could be such a pair. "Un-wane" would more strictly implying "undoing a wane" which could be seen as a separate concept from "wax." "Not waning _or_ waxing but simply doing nothing at all" is something else entirely; I wouldn't consider it a _reversal_ or an _opposite_.

Comment: I'm unable to interpret what you say other than: *The opposite of waning is not waning (i.e. - 'unwaning'). | The reversal of waning is that action backwards (i.e. - 'waxing').* The "(i.e.)" bits are added by me there, but you used the opposite word in each case.

Comment: @Fumble: That is because _un-_ doesn't always mean _not_. For instance, _undo_ does not mean _not doing_. Same with words such as, _untie_; _unmask_.

Comment: I'm not talking about what the actual words mean - just the logic of your example, which seems contradictory to its conclusions for me.

Comment: @Fumble: They aren't contradictory. I have no idea why you think they are. To say it _again_: The opposite of something is just the opposite of it; a reversal is essentially the undoing of the thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's all to do with vagueness about the exact meaning of *negation, opposite, etc.* Necessary vagueness, because the world itself isn't black and white, so it's not always obvious how to apply 'disembodied' logic.

In the case of *unwaning*, as OP says, if it existed, the word would presumably mean *not waning* (i.e. – exactly the same as *unwaxing*, if we postulate such a word and sense).

The reason for this is simply that when we imagine the sense of *unwaning* we're likely to consider it within the context of a continuous oscillating activity, where negation invokes the idea of that activity not occurring at all.

The alternative, obviously, is to consider *waning* as one part of the two-phase process, giving *waxing* as the other.

This particular example covers just one of an almost infinite number of different ways things can be considered 'opposite'. Take **loved**, for example. Most people's first suggestion for an 'opposite' is probably 'hated'. It might take a while to realise that from a different standpoint, **unloved** is a more precise negation.

TL;DR: There are many different kinds of 'opposite'. The two in OP's example are perhaps the most common; *reversal* and *absence* (per @Hellion's comment, often indicated by *un-* and *non-*).

Comment: "Unwaning" could either mean, "Not waning" or "Undoing waning." Since the word doesn't actually exist, it is ambiguous.

Comment: Since, as you say, the word doesn't exist, it seems only reasonable that if we're going to reference it at all here, we should go with the meaning assigned to it by OP.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. I am not blaming anyone for the ambiguity; I was just pointing out that it exists.

Comment: Interesting that you should have brought up love: *unwaning love* is a phrase I would almost *expect* to see coined in poetry on multiple occasions, even if it doesn't reach the sort of usage that would get *unwaning* into a dictionary. It is a good formation, and certainly shorter and more euphonic than *undiminishing*.